# How to inline in C++ self modifying assembly code?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, self-modifying

How would I inline this in C++ function.

```
0041F84E   . 7B 02          JPO SHORT Unmodifi.0041F852
0041F850     B8             DB B8
0041F851     00             DB 00
0041F852   . 8B46 38        MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+38]
0041F855   . 8B56 24        MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+24]
0041F858   . 8B4E 10        MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+10]
0041F85B   . 81EA 8B4B8636  SUB EDX,36864B8B
```

How would I put 
`DB B8` 
`DB 00`

```
void test() {
    __asm {
        ...
        JPO label_0041F852
        __emit 0xB8
        __emit 00
label_0041F852:
        MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x38]
        MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x24]
        MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x10]
        SUB EDX,0x36864B8B
        ...
    }
}
```

**error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'constant'**
Error executing cl.exe.

I don't think I can put this in the `.data` section, I've read thats all I can do to include bytes like this.

Comment: Modern systems generally forbid program segments that are [both writable and executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit#Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: Are you intending to modify the `DB 00` byte at run-time from outside? I can't see any code in this snippet that modifies anything.

Comment: umm `JPO` instruction is code modifier, if jump isn't taken.

Comment: SMC still works fine, just specify executable|writable on the .text section of the executable. Or dynamically allocate memory that is both executable and writable.

Comment: [`_emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b80826t\(v=vs.80\).aspx) should work.

Comment: Compatibility note: x64 does not accept `__asm`, making this code quite unportable for the forseeable future.

Comment: Perhaps I'm stupid, but I'm missing something here. How does this code modify itself? `B8 00` just loads a register with zero, right?

Comment: `B8` is the start of `MOV EAX, imm32`. It's presumably being modified elsewhere or is designed to overlap the following instruction.

Comment: Well, that's what I've been trying to find out -- who modifies this code? Because it certainly doesn't modify itself.

Comment: @TonyK try it yourself in ollydbg, above `JPO` instruction is some logic.. which when computed can set `PF` flag to 0 or one depending on how this flag is set.. if `'PF` = 0 then it will jump to `MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x38]` if `PF` = 1 then `B8 00 8B 46` gets modified into new instruction `MOV  EAX, 38468B00h` hence being hidden code/ self modifying code. This is the obfuscation I cannot defeat and resorted to making ASM emulator, and now trying to inline code to skip wasting my time. Don't have enough room to recreate this without `JPO` in same area as well

Comment: @rubenvb yes this is another problem dang it

Comment: @SSpoke: That's not code modification. That's just re-aligning the instruction stream.

Comment: Alright there buddy I call that code modification.. give me a example of code modification in assembly? Of course it's just re-aligning how it read instructions. But isn't that modification of code after all?

Comment: Okay maybe code written in a notepad which then is compiled to a program then ran another code generator that saved to notepad which was compiled and ran again is considered code modification haha I did that one before. :D or maybe just a recursive loop rofl, damn im stoned as hell.

Comment: `rofl` is the Rotate Left Through Overflow Flag instruction, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer-length comment to reply to SSpoke's request for an example. A long time ago, when emulating Turing machines was a cool thing to do, I wrote a Turing machine emulator program to search for [busy beavers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) on a DEC Vax minicomputer. When the program decided which Turing machine to try next, it compiled the machine code for the Turing machine into an array, and called the array as if it was a function. (All this was written in `C`.)

That's self-modifying code. To run it, you need an area of memory that is simultaneously writable and executable.

Your code is not self-modifying -- you don't write to it at all. So you can run it in a read-only program segment.